# How to cache page in jquery mobile for android

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile-application

I am working on a mobile application with phonegap and jquery mobile for android. It is working properly but it takes so much time to get data from server.

I want to cache its pages so if user come back on same page he can view same page.
I am using jquery mobile caching code but it is not working.

I am using this code `data-dom-cache="true"` for cache

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.appView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/find.html");
    }
```

Comment: can you put some code example so people can understand your problem easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache is not working in my app so I stored all json data in localstorage by doing this

```
window.localStorage.setItem("ALL_USERS",JSON.stringify(data));
```

where `data` is json object I retrieve from server. 
And next time i retrieve data from localstorage

```
window.localStorage.setItem("ALL_USERS",JSON.stringify(data));
users = JSON.parse(users);
```

This solution solved my problem hope it will help others.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Call below code in onCreate() method of your Android application activity file:

```
super.appView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```

The above method uses cache if content is there, even if expired (eg, history nav). If it is not in the cache, load from network

Please look WebSettings constants for cache settings :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html

Comment: When i used this app is crash.

Comment: Please use your onCreate method as below :public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 70000);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/find.html");
  
  if (super.appView != null) {
   super.appView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
 }
    }